# Changing a csv file, reading and writing with dynamic mapping

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

Assume I have a large csv file that I'd like to read, modify and write back. Perhaps I want to change a field separator from comma to tab. Perhaps I want to change the quotation character from ' to ". Or may be I want to add a plus sign to each value in the first column. Since the file is large, I do not want to load it in memory all at once, I'd like to read it record by record.

So I write a code like this:

```
var inPath = @"infile.txt";
var outPath = @"outfile.txt";

CsvConfiguration readCf = GetReadConfiguration();
CsvConfiguration writeCf = GetWriteConfiguration();

using (var streamin = new FileStream(inPath, FileMode.Open))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(streamin))
{
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, readCf))
    using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter(outPath), writeCf))
    {
        while (csvReader.Read())
        {
            var currentRecord = csvReader.GetRecord<dynamic>();
            UpdateRecord(currentRecord);
            csvWriter.WriteRecord(currentRecord);
        }
    }
}
```

This fails at run time with the following error:

> Types that inherit IEnumerable cannot be auto mapped. Did you
>   accidentally call GetRecord or WriteRecord which acts on a single
>   record instead of calling GetRecords or WriteRecords which acts on a
>   list of records?

Note, that nothing interesting happens in `UpdateRecord`, in fact this line above can be completely commented out.

What happens is that `GetRecord` returns an `ExpandoObject` and then `WriteRecord` chokes on this object.

What is the best way to make this work?

**Update**
Just so it's clear: I fully realize that I'm getting this error is because [CSVHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) does not support `ExpandoObject`s for `WriteRecord` call. I'm looking for suggestions, for easiest way to make this work.

Comment: The error is telling you to use GetRecords (plural) instead of singular. I mean it is hinting it. Did you try that?

Comment: @CodingYoshi, nope, that's not what I need.

Comment: Look at Mar L's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294738/read-all-values-from-csv-into-a-list-using-csvhelper) and see if that helps you.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, thank you, no it does not. The answer suggests not using CSVHelper. I need CSVHelper because this is a non trivial CSV file. It has quoted fields, some quoted fields are multi-line, etc. CSVHelper is perfect for parsing this file and writing it back, if only we could get around this deficiency.

Comment: If all you are doing is changing CSV characteristics (like ticks etc) rather than the data, couldnt you just read the raw fields (untyped)

Comment: @Plutonix, sorry, could you explain that? That is I do not understand how reading raw untyped fields is different from what I'm doing.

Comment: Basically, its what Mr Close suggests in the linked post.  Rather than mapping it to any object, get the lines as a string array.  The link may have changed since neither answer suggests not using CSVHelper

Comment: @Plutonix, well that accounts for the reading part, put then I'll have to format the result for writing manually. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, there appears to be no way to pass Writer an array - a loop on the fields I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that ability to write `ExpandoObject` is added in [this commit](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/commit/8904f5122c039a27314ca711eaf59b2bdcd40dc9).

Note that this is not in the latest nuget release (2.16.3 as of the time of writing) but for the next 3.x release. If it's an option for you get latest beta from github and use that.

If you do, note that you will have to call `NextRecord` after each `WriteRecord`. In 2.16.3 CVSHelper would call it for you, so it's a bit of a breaking API change

Comment: The old version gave me `CsvConfigurationException: Types that inherit IEnumerable cannot be auto mapped. Did you accidentally call GetRecord or WriteRecord which acts on a single record instead of calling GetRecords or WriteRecords which acts on a list of records?` and the new version (3.0) gives me `CsvTypeConverterException: Converting IEnumerable types is not supported for a single field. If you want to do this, create your own ITypeConverter and register it in the TypeConverterFactory by calling AddConverter.`