# How to use CSV Helper to read line by line in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper, line-by-line

So this is the code I am using currently, but I don't specifically want to create my own reader. My problem is that I want to read a full csv file line by line, but the file contents will change from time to time, so it has to be generic.

This is what I am using currently,

```
try
{
    var Lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    var csvRawData = from line in Lines select (line.Split(',')).ToArray();
    var csvData = csvRawData.ToList();
    return csvData;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    Logger.Log(ex.Message, true);
    return null;
}
```

The return csvData is of type List. I then just separate the content out from it manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33294738/read-all-values-from-csv-into-a-list-using-csvhelper

Comment: Take a look at Linq To CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say `CsvHelper`, but from your code it doesn't look like you're actually using it. If you are using it, you can use the `GetField` methods to pull a field by header name of index. Take a look at the documentation for more information on how to use it.
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of reading line by line, where the second line has a different 'type' then the first line:

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            csv.Read();

            Type1 sample = new Type1();
            sample.Id = csv.GetField<int>(0);
            sample.Lines = csv.GetField<int>(1);

            csv.Read();

            Type2 sample2 = new Type2();
            sample2.Angle = csv.GetField<double>(0);
            sample2.Distance = csv.GetField<int>(1);
        }
    }
```