# Upload CSV data into SQL database using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, csvhelper

I am trying to insert data from a `.csv` file into my database, but anytime I upload data, the record is empty.

This is my code so far:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportFromExcel(IFormFile formFile)
{
    var data = new MemoryStream();
    await formFile.CopyToAsync(data);

    data.Position = 0;
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(data);

    var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                        {
                            HasHeaderRecord = true,
                            HeaderValidated = null,
                            MissingFieldFound = null
                        });

    var Name = csvReader.GetField(0).ToString();
    var dep = "cccccccccc";
    var pos = "bbbbbbbbbbb";

    await dcx.Participants.AddAsync(new Participant
                                        {
                                            Name = Name,
                                            Position = pos,
                                            Department = dep,
                                        });
    dcx.SaveChanges();
    
    return ViewComponent("ViewParticipants");
}
```

This is the sample data in my database table:

[image]

Comment: the csv is not saved on the server and i do not want to save it on the server either. i just want to upload and read data

Comment: You never call `csvReader.Read()` to read the first row.  See [How to use CSV Helper to read line by line in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58670866).

Comment: You should also dispose of your `StreamReader` and `CsvReader` properly via a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should call `csvReader.Read()` to read the file row first.

You can refer to the following test code, it works fine.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportFromExcel(IFormFile formFile)
{
     var data = new MemoryStream();
     await formFile.CopyToAsync(data);

     data.Position = 0;
     using (var reader = new StreamReader(data))
     {
           var bad = new List<string>();
           var conf = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
           {
                HasHeaderRecord = true,
                HeaderValidated = null,
                MissingFieldFound = null,
                BadDataFound = context =>
                {
                     bad.Add(context.RawRecord);
                }
           };
           using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, conf))
           {
                while (csvReader.Read())
                {
                     var Name = csvReader.GetField(0).ToString();
                     var pos = csvReader.GetField(1).ToString();
                     var dep = csvReader.GetField(2).ToString();
                        
                     await dcx.Participants.AddAsync(new Participant
                     {
                          Name = Name,
                          Position = pos,
                          Department = dep,
                     });
                     dcx.SaveChanges();
                }
           }
     }
     return ViewComponent("ViewParticipants");
}
```

Test Result:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Chen your answer helped a lot. I am grateful.  but does it have a limit to the data it can read?

Comment: In my opinion,there is no limitation imposed by `CsvHelper` though.If you run into problems,you can try not doing a `ToList()` and put it in a loop instead. This will pull one record at a time. Set a break point in the loop and see if you're getting anything that way. If so, make a counter and see how many records it pulls.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the headers of your CSV match up to the names of the columns in your database, you should be able to do something like this.  If the names don't match, you can use `.Name("CsvColumnName")` in `ParticipantMap` to add the name of the column in the CSV file. Example: `Map(r => r.Description).Name("MyCsvDescription");`.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportFromExcel(IFormFile formFile)
{
    var data = new MemoryStream();
    await formFile.CopyToAsync(data);

    data.Position = 0;

    var conf = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
         HasHeaderRecord = true,
         HeaderValidated = null,
         MissingFieldFound = null,
         BadDataFound = context =>
         {
              bad.Add(context.RawRecord);
         }
    };
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(data))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, config)) {

        csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<ParticipantMap>();
        var records = csvReader.GetRecords<Participant>().ToList();

        var dep = "cccccccccc";
        var pos = "bbbbbbbbbbb";

        records.ForEach(r =>
        {
            r.Department = dep;
            r.Position = pos;
        });

        await dcx.Participants.AddRangeAsync(records);
        dcx.SaveChanges();
    }
    
    return ViewComponent("ViewParticipants");
}

public class ParticipantMap : ClassMap<Participant>
{
    public ParticipantMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Map(r => r.Department).Ignore();
        Map(r => r.Position).Ignore();
    }
}
```