# Looping to a specific value in IEnumerable list

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am using CsvHelper library to read through a list of records in a csv file, and would like to know how I can read loop through the list from a specific value or row.

My CSV file data:

```
123456
546879
258963
147852
654789
321654
```

Currently my code is as follows:

```
Currently my code:
int controlid = 0; //This value is read from a file 

using (CsvReader csvread = new CsvReader(inputFilePath))
IEnumerable<dynamic> records = csvread.GetRecords<dynamic>();

for (int i = controlid; i < records.Count(); i++)
{
    // I get "Argument out of bounds" error here
    customerID = records.ElementAt(i);

    console.writeLine(customerID);
    controlID++;
}
```

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33295046/169714 and add an `if(yourvar == controlid){ //.. }` in the loop.

Comment: Repeatedly calling ElementAt() can be very inefficient. Look up Linq's Skip() and SkipWhile()

Comment: Or materialize the list from the beginning of using `ToList`.

Comment: I don't think the dupe is a good match, here the exception occurs inside a `i < records.Count()` guard.

Comment: You should be clear about controlid/controlID , are they really different or is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: Typo: IEnumberable → IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

```
using (CsvReader csvread = new CsvReader(inputFilePath))
IEnumerable<dynamic> records = csvread.GetRecords<dynamic>();
records.SkipWhile(e => e != controlid).ToList().ForEach(e =>
{
       console.writeLine(e);
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you, tried this method, but getting a RunTimebinderException Error [!= cannot be applied to operands of type System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject]

Comment: I'm not realy knowing the System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject.
Please try e => !e.Equals(controlid)

Comment: Typo: IEnumberable → IEnumerable